# Add double quotes to variable to escape space

Tags: powershell

I am running a script which has $FileName variable containing the absolute path with spaces. Due to the space within the directory name and file name, the script fails to executes without finding the actual path. All I need is to add $FilePath within double quotes. How should I append double quotes in the beginning and end of a string?

For example

```
"X:\Movies\File One\File One.txt"
```

Script:

```
$FilePath = Join-Path $Path $($Dir + "\" + $File + “.txt”)
$FilePath
```

Current OutPut:

```
X:\Movies\File One\File One.txt
```

Comment: does this work for you? `"'$path\$dir\$file.txt'"`

Comment: `$FilePath = Join-Path $Path $($Dir + "\" + $File + ".txt")` could be re-written as `$FilePath = Join-Path $Path (Join-Path $Dir ($File + ".txt"))`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In addition to the backtick escape character (`` ` ``), you can use the `-f` format operator:

```
$FilePath = Join-Path $Dir -ChildPath "$File.txt"
$FilePathWithQuotes = '"{0}"' -f $FilePath
```

This will ensure that `$FilePath` is expanded before being placed in the string

Answer (score 2):

```
$FilePath = Join-Path $Path $($Dir + "\" + $File + “.txt”)
"`"$FilePath`""
```

...would output...

```
"X:\Movies\File One\File One.txt"
```

This is an example of [variable expansion in strings](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/07/15/variable-expansion-in-strings-and-here-strings/).

Of course, if the path you want to quote could contain `"` quotes itself, for example in a future "powershell for linux", you'd need to escape the `"` in a context specific way.

Comment: Presumably the curly quotes here were mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

Any one of these should work:

```
$FilePath1 = """" + (Join-Path $Path $($Dir + "\" + $File + ".txt")) + """"
$FilePath2 = "`"" + (Join-Path $Path $($Dir + "\" + $File + ".txt")) + "`""
$FilePath3 = '"{0}"' -f (Join-Path $Path $($Dir + "\" + $File + ".txt"))
$FilePath4 = '"' + (Join-Path $Path $($Dir + "\" + $File + ".txt")) + '"'
$FilePath5 = [char]34 + (Join-Path $Path $($Dir + "\" + $File + ".txt")) + [char]34
```

Answer (score 0):

fastest solution (but a bit ugly) to add quotes around any string:

```
$dir = "c:\temp"
$file = "myfile"
$filepath = [string]::Join("", """", $dir,"\", $file, ".txt", """")
```