# How ignore spaces and special characters in folder names

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

We have storage shared as `\\192.168.1.26\e$`. There are several folders (all shared) which are used by different departments. I wanted to get the *owners* and *users* who has access to folders, which are in those share folders.

I have created this PowerShell script for that:

```
$path = "\\192.168.1.26\e$\"
$getlist = Get-ChildItem -Path \\192.1681.26\e$ | Select-Object Name
foreach ($folder in $getlist) {
    $out = '\\192.168.1.26\e$\{0}' -f $folder.name
    #write-host $out
    #prep arguments
    $getargs = $out,'-ad | where {$_.psiscontainer -eq $true} | get-acl | Select-Object path,owner,accesstostring | fl'
    write-host $getargs
    gci $getargs
}
```

From `$getlist = Get-ChildItem -Path \\192.1681.26\e$ | Select-Object Name` I get all folders listed. However some folder names contains spaces and special characters, which causes the rest of the script to fail.

Examples:

```
It-&-Network
MIS
Account
Sales Reports
Market Report
DATA
```

When I run the below command it works as expected

`gci \\192.168.1.26\e$\MIS | where {$_.psiscontainer -eq $true} | get-acl | Select-Object path,owner,group,accesstostring | fl`

But I get an error on this command:

`gci \\192.168.1.26\e$\Sales Reports | where {$_.psiscontainer -eq $true} | get-acl | Select-Object path,owner,group,accesstostring | fl`

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Use get-childitem -literalpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution from [Add double quotes to variable to escape space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35308981/add-double-quotes-to-variable-to-escape-space)

```
$path = '\\localhost\f$\tmp'
$getlist = Get-ChildItem -Path $path | Select-Object Name
foreach ($folder in $getlist) {
    $out = '"{0}\{1}"' -f $path,$folder.name 
    $getargs = $out
    write-host $getargs
    $extraparam = '-ad | where {$_.psiscontainer -eq $true} | get-acl | Select-Object path,owner,accesstostring | fl'
    $run_command = 'gci {0} {1}' -f $getargs,$extraparam
    write-host $run_command
    Invoke-Expression $run_command
}
```

Also it can helps you - https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-esc.html
Updated for local disk example, working on my machine.

Comment: Tried that already It didn't worked it says `gci : An unexpected network error occurred.`

Comment: Does it work when you try to run `gci` using parameters from console?
I mean `gci '\\192.168.1.26\e$\Sales Reports' | where {$_.psiscontainer -eq $true} | get-acl | Select-Object path,owner,group,accesstostring | fl` does work fine?

Comment: Sorry My mistake, I was checking on folder on which I didnt have rights, Now I have it. However getting below strange error. `Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'C:\'\192.168.1.26\e$\Sales report'' because it does not exist.`
I have no idea why it is going to C:\

Comment: I didn't find more elegant way to send parameters using pipes that updated version

Comment: Check that version, I think that the solution you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated. With minor change in `$out` it exactly works as I needed.