# The name of the workbook or view to export cannot include spaces. Use the normalized name of the workbook or view as it appears in the URL

Tags: excel, powershell, tableau-api

I have two Excel Copies for two users to run the same process. 2 copies were made because both users have different versions of tabcmd due to PC upgrade for one user.

I have written a Powershell script and I have check both copies and they are both the same.

This process works for one user whose tab cmd is:

```
C:\Program Files\Tableau\Tableau Server\10.2\extras\Command Line Utility
```

The other's is

```
C:\Program Files\Tableau\Tableau Server\10.5\extras\Command Line Utility\
```

But gets the error:

> "The name of the workbook or view to export cannot include spaces. Use
>   the normalized name of the workbook or view as it appears in the URL"

I have included this in the Powershell in both copies:

```
.\tabcmd export $cmdstr.Replace("$"+"Submarket_1", $Submarket_1)
```

I have checked everything else and all looks the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add double quotes to variable to escape space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35308981/add-double-quotes-to-variable-to-escape-space)

Comment: Why does one finish without a slash? Also, would it not be simpler to upgrade the pc's to the same spec? or are you going to say it's an IT Dept issue...

Comment: That was my typo. So the user it is not working for has upgraded and the one that it is working for 'yet to upgrade'.

Comment: without knowing what the command for `export` resolves to when you do `$cmdstr.Replace("$"+"Submarket_1", $Submarket_1)` it is impossible to answer this. If you want someone to help you, you need to give more details.