# How can I change a part of non-static text within double quotes using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to replace certain text within a file, the challenge is, that text is not always the same and may be blank and contain a space between double quotes " ", or entirely different name inside the quotes altogether.

Here is the code:

```
$NewModelPath = "Stuff_I_Want_to_put_in" 
 $PathtoText="C:\Temp\TEST.txt"
 $EmptyVariable="`*"`*"*"    # I am attempting to declare there may be an empty space between the quotes or any text/number inside the double quotes 
                                          
 $Catalog="<add key=`"Catalog.Repository`" value="$EmptyVariable" />"

 $fix_Catalog="<add key=`"Models.Catalog.Repository`" value=`"$NewModelPath`" />"

 (Get-Content $PathtoText) -replace "$Catalog","$fix_ModelCatalog" | Set-Content $Pathtotext -Force 
 -Encoding UTF8 -ErrorAction Stop
```

Here is the problem:

the key <add key=`"Catalog.Repository`" value="$EmptyVariable" />" may look like any of the 3 below:

```
<add key=`"Catalog.Repository`" value=" " />"
<add key=`"Catalog.Repository`" value="\\\Server\Path1" />"
<add key=`"Catalog.Repository`" value="\\\Computer1\Path123\Extra123" />"
```

How do I change the text inside double quotes whether it is blank or has any kind of text in it or character?

thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add double quotes to variable to escape space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35308981/add-double-quotes-to-variable-to-escape-space)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're reading $Catalog from a file that looks like this:

If that is the case you can use the Split method to break it down on the double-quotes, replace the appropriate indexes then do the replace, e.g.

```
$Lines = Get-Content -Path G:\BEKDocs\TestDoc.txt

ForEach ( $Catalog in $Lines) {
  $x = $Catalog.Split('"')
#  $x.Count
#  $x
  $x[1] = 'Models.Catalog.Repository'
  $x[3] = 'Stuff-I-Want-Here'
  $fix_Catalog = $x -join '"'

  $Catalog
  $fix_Catalog
}
```

Output:

```
<add key="Catalog.Repository" value=" " />
<add key="Models.Catalog.Repository" value="Stuff-I-Want-Here" />
<add key="Catalog.Repository" value="\\\Server\Path1" />
<add key="Models.Catalog.Repository" value="Stuff-I-Want-Here" />
<add key="Catalog.Repository" value="\\\Computer1\Path123\Extra123" />
<add key="Models.Catalog.Repository" value="Stuff-I-Want-Here" />
```

The commented out lines are just so I could see which indexes to use (debugging).
This should give you enough info to integrate it into your code.

HTH

Comment: Sorry for late reply, this does fix the issue